# One handed controller to turn off all lights in room that can be tied to wrist

Tags: internet-of-things

The lights will be on I'll curl up in a ball on a bed and begin to fall asleep. For some reason, sometimes I fall asleep better when the lights are on. However, if I get up to turn off the lights, I usually lose that warm/cozy/comfortable feeling and have trouble falling asleep.

My quality of sleep is much better when all of the lights are off. If I don't turn off all the lights, I often don't feel very rested the morning after.

**Eventually, I'd like to have small/lightweight/comfortable to the touch handheld device that I can temporarily fasten to my wrist/loop around my wrist that can turn off all the lights including miscellaneous lights indicating that a laptop is charging/ethernet wire lights etc say within 3 seconds and have the light bulbs dim slowly during those 3 seconds as they turn off.**

> Now my gut instinct is that someone will or has made a clever smartphone app to do this. So in that situation the hardware would be your smartphone. There's a few reasons why I'd be hesitant if a smartphone solution to this came along and here's why. Feel free to address them:

1. Plenty of smartphones are slippery- I don't think you could tie a
   smartphone to your hand comfortably
2. The heat your body under the covers might not be good for the
   smartphone
3. Could pretty easily knock the smartphone off the bed onto the floor

> When I was a little boy, sometimes my parents would see that I had fallen asleep and turn off the lights -> Things would work great then. Perhaps I'm going about this wrong and there is actually hardware for the lights in your room to know that you have fallen asleep?